# Brand new Sony Vaio Laptop ( E series) screen broken internally?

Tags: sony-vaio

My new sony vaio laptop is 3 month old. Recently, I finished working on the laptop, shut it down. I woke up the next morning, switched on the laptop and the screen has developed a black feather (leaf shape) on the left side. and it is now spreading.  This screen will work how long?

No Cracks on my screen, no scratches. My laptop never dropped. The Service center refused to take the warranty they are saying the laptop is dropped or kept a weight on laptop that causes a physical display. I don't know why they are not taking warranty , without my mistake.

Comment: Well, we can't answer how long it will work for! You may want to take a picture of the screen and post it, although you've tried hard to describe the issue, a picture is better in cases like this. I would also review this Google search - it appears [you're not alone with this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=black+leaf+shape+on+screen) and it may help you win the argument.

Comment: Does your screen look like http://www.technibble.com/forums/attachment.php?s=7858b7246cf1055e66fc68c21cd04901&attachmentid=1504&d=1304067947

Comment: I need 10 reputation to attach the picture.

Comment: But the screen is not that much damaged like the one you send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably means the screen has a faulty connection to its main board! Flat TV screens (LCD/LED) are connected via flex or cable wires to its mother board. IF the connection is poor then this can be the result.

[Source](http://www.askmefast.com/My_laptop_screen_has_a_black_leaf_with_multicolored_lines_across_it__What_is_happening-qna4295719.html)

You may also note, that via the source, others are complaining of the same issue (that it just stopped working without anything physical (although not with the same machine))